# How to place a 2D image selected from Network/Assets on a Plane using AR in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, arcore

I am developing an **Flutter Android Application** which should scan the plane from device camera and after getting a surface place the image onto it.

I tried **[arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ar_flutter_plugin)** to implement and by following available tutorials I was able to render 3D images objects on a plane using AR, but I want to place only a 2D image.

Could anyone assist me with that?

The code to convert 2D image into 3D Obj and place it is below:

```
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector64;

class ArEarthMapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ArEarthMapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ArEarthMapScreen> createState() => _ArEarthMapScreenState();
}

class _ArEarthMapScreenState extends State<ArEarthMapScreen> {
  ArCoreController? argumentedRealityCoreController;

  argumentedRealityViewCreated(ArCoreController coreController) {
    argumentedRealityCoreController = coreController;

    displayEarthMapSphere(argumentedRealityCoreController!);
  }

  displayEarthMapSphere(ArCoreController coreController) async {
    final ByteData textureBytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/earth_map.jpg");

    final materials = ArCoreMaterial(
      color: Colors.blue,
      textureBytes: textureBytes.buffer.asUint8List(),
    );

    final tempPlane = ArCoreImage(
      height: 10,
      width: 10,
      bytes: textureBytes.buffer.asUint8List(),
    );

    final sphere = ArCoreSphere(materials: [materials]);

    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: sphere,
      position: vector64.Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
    );

    argumentedRealityCoreController!.addArCoreNode(node);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    argumentedRealityCoreController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ArCoreView(
        onArCoreViewCreated: argumentedRealityViewCreated,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```